# Rust thread trait example does not compile

Tags: multithreading, rust, move, traits

My example is almost identical to the one published on
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fb2ac23ffc1e3a676df6a2add351d78c

but mine does not compile with message

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Box<dyn Process + Send>>`
  --> src/main.rs:35:19
   |
35 |             spawn(self.tasks[i], txi);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Box<dyn Process + Send>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::sync::mpsc::Sender;
use std::thread;
use std::time;

trait Process {
    fn run(&mut self) -> String;
}

struct Runner {
    tasks: Vec<Box<dyn Process + Send>>,
}

fn spawn<T: ?Sized>(mut task: Box<T>, tx: Sender<String>)
where
    T: Process + Send + 'static,
{
    thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        tx.send(format!("{:?}", task.run()))
    });
}

impl Runner {
    fn new() -> Self {
        Runner { tasks: Vec::new() }
    }
    fn subscribe(&mut self, p: Box<(dyn Process + Send)>) {
        self.tasks.push(p);
    }
    fn start(&mut self) {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        for i in 0..self.tasks.len() {
            let txi = tx.clone();
            spawn(self.tasks[i], txi);
        }
        for r in rx {
            println!("Received : {:?}", r);
        }
    }
}

struct Foo {
    name: String,
    value: u32,
}
impl Foo {
    fn set_value(&mut self, v: u32) {
        self.value = v
    }
}
impl Process for Foo {
    fn run(&mut self) -> String {
        println!("Running {}", self.name);
        self.value = 33;
        println!("The value of {} is {}", self.name, self.value);
        self.name.clone()
    }
}

struct Bar {
    name: String,
    values: Vec<u32>,
}
impl Bar {
    fn new(nm: &str, sz: usize) -> Self {
        let array = Box::new(vec![0; sz]);
        let mut ret = Bar {
            name: nm.to_string(),
            values: *array,
        };
        for i in 0..sz {
            ret.write(i, 0);
        }
        ret
    }
    fn read(&mut self, addr: usize) -> u32 {
        self.values[addr]
    }
    fn write(&mut self, addr: usize, v: u32) {
        self.values[addr] = v;
    }
}
impl Process for Bar {
    fn run(&mut self) -> String {
        println!("Bar {} is sized {}", self.name, self.values.len());
        self.write(3, 42);
        println!("value 3 is {}", self.read(3));
        self.name.clone()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut r = Runner::new();
    let foo: Foo = Foo {
        name: "foo".to_string(),
        value: 0,
    };
    let bar: Bar = Bar::new("bar", 10);
    r.subscribe(Box::new(foo));
    r.subscribe(Box::new(bar));
    r.start();
}
```

I would like to understand the difference...

Comment: Please provide the complete error message given by the compiler not just a single line of it / the error given by your IDE.

Comment: Here it is    rustc -o spawn spawn.rs
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Box<dyn Process + Send>>`
  --> spawn.rs:32:19
   |
32 |             spawn(self.tasks[i], txi);
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `Box<dyn Process + Send>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0507`.

Comment: Well, in the working code they have owned `Animal`s, in your code you don't have owned `Process`es.

Comment: Do not put the error message in a comment. Instead you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75789511/edit) your question to add the message directly to it.

Comment: So, how can I make my code work. I need to have the subscribe facilty in my real code.

Comment: I believe it's because you are trying to move ownership of the `self.tasks[i]` value to the spawn function. But it fails, because the value returned from `self.tasks[i]` is still owned by the `self.tasks`. What you need to do is to move the value out of the `self.tasks` or create a copy of it by deriving Copy trait of the value. To move the value out of the `self.tasks` you can call `self.tasks.remove(i)` which will return the value and release its ownership from `Vec<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

### About the error

The error explains:

```rs
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<Box<dyn Process + Send>>`
```

This is the same error you get when compiling:

```rs
let strings = vec![String::from("test")];

take_ownership(strings[0]); // error, because it moves `strings[0]` out of the `strings`
```

### Fixes

Referring to this example, this can be fixed by cloning so it doesn't takes the item from the vector:

```rs
let strings = vec![String::from("test")];

take_ownership(strings[0].clone()); // no problem,
// because now a clone is passed into the function, and `strings[0]` stays in `strings`
```

Or use a struct that can be copied (implements `Copy`)

```rs
let strs = vec!["test"];

take_ownership(strs[0]);
```

### Applying to your code

**Make a clone of the structs**

```rs
// first, make sure that the item can be cloned by requiring the `Clone` trait
struct Runner {
    tasks: Vec<Box<dyn Process + Send + Clone>>,
}

// line 35
spawn(self.tasks[i].clone(), txi);
```

> Or as the compiler suggests, impl `Copy` (don't think it will work for you, as `String` does not impl `Copy`)

Hope this is clear

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tips. The solution

```
struct Runner {
    tasks: Vec<Box<dyn Process + Send + Clone>>,
}
```

does not compile. Finally, I got this compiling and running

```
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::{Sender};
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::time;

trait Process : CloneProcess {
    fn run(&mut self) -> String;
}

trait CloneProcess {
    fn clone_me<'a>(&self) -> Box<dyn Process + Send>;
}
impl<T> CloneProcess for T
where T: Process + Send + Clone + 'static,
{
    fn clone_me(&self) -> Box<dyn Process + Send> {
        Box::new(self.clone())
    }
}
impl Clone for Box<dyn Process + Send> {
    fn clone(&self) ->Self { self.clone_me()
    }
}
struct Runner {
    tasks: Vec<Box< dyn Process + Send>>,
    //    ready_queue: VecDeque<Arc<Mutex<dyn Process>>>,
    //   waiting_queue:VecDeque<Arc<Mutex<dyn Process>>>  ,
}

fn spawn<T: ?Sized>(mut bt : Box<T>, tx: Sender<String>)
where T: Process + Send + 'static,
{
    thread::spawn(move || {
        thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(1));
        bt.run();
        tx.send("done".to_string()).unwrap();
    });
}

impl Runner{
    fn new() -> Self {
        Runner{tasks:Vec::new(),
               // ready_queue: VecDeque::new(),
               //      waiting_queue:VecDeque::new()
        }
    }
    fn subscribe(&mut self, p: Box<dyn Process + Send>)
    {
        self.tasks.push(p);
    }
    fn start(&mut self) {
        let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();
        for i in 0..self.tasks.len() {
            println!("spawning");
            let task = self.tasks[i].clone();
            spawn(task, tx.clone());
        };
        drop(tx);
        for r in rx {
            println!("Received : {:?}", r);
        };
    }
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo {
    name: String,
    value: u32,
}
impl Foo {
    fn set_value(&mut self, v: u32) {self.value = v }
}
impl Process for Foo {
    fn run(&mut self) -> String {
        self.set_value(33);
        println!("The value of {} is {}", self.name, self.value);
        self.name.clone()
    }
}
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bar {
    name: String,
    values: Vec<u32>
}
impl Bar {
    fn new(nm: &str, sz: usize) -> Self{
        let array = Box::new(vec![0;sz]);
        let mut ret = Bar{ name:nm.to_string(),
                           values: *array
        };
        for i in 0..sz {
            ret.write(i, 0);
        }
        ret
    }
    fn read(&mut self, addr: usize) -> u32 {self.values[addr]}
    fn write(&mut self, addr: usize, v: u32) {self.values[addr]=v;}
}
impl Process for Bar {
    fn run(&mut self) -> String {
        println!("Bar {} is sized {}",
                 self.name,
                 self.values.len());
        self.write(3,42);
        println!("value 3 is {}", self.read(3));
        self.name.clone()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut r = Runner::new();
    let foo: Foo = Foo {
        name: "foo".to_string(),
        value: 0,
    };
    let bar: Bar = Bar::new("bar",10);
    r.subscribe(Box::new(foo));
    r.subscribe(Box::new(bar));
    r.start();
}
```